# Can you fake the timestamp of DeltaTable history in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

For testing purposes I wanna get the version of a table by timestamp using
e.g. `option={'timestampAsOf': '2022-01-01 23:59:59'}`

But as I understand the `timestamp` in the `history` is always the current timestamp of the operation.

Can I fake the timestamp, i.e. force it to be some determined datetime?

That way I could write better tests!

I tried `freezgun.freeze_time` but that didn't get me far!

Any ideas? Maybe @Denny Lee

Comment: Question is not very clear, can you please provide current input and desired output ?

Comment: Structured example in opened issue: github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/1553

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now, you cannot change the current timestamp of an operation.  Saying this, perhaps open an issue in the [Delta Lake GitHub](https://go.delta.io/github) and we can work together on doing something like this.

BTW, we have an incubation project called [Delta Acceptance Testing or DAT](https://github.com/delta-incubator/dat) which should help your testing.

Comment: Hello Denny, thanks for responding :) 
I opened the issue here: https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/1553
Happy to see this move forward.

Answer (score 1):

edit: Leaving this up for posterity, but my answer is wrong - you cannot falsify these because the creation timestamp for the file chunks also matters

original:

You would have to edit the commit log. Each delta table has a folder called `_delta_log` that contains the commit log for that table. Within that folder, there's a json file for each version of the folder. That json file has a property called "commitInfo" which in turn has a "timestamp", e.g.

```
{
  "commitInfo": {
    "timestamp": 12345678 <- set this to something else?
  }
}
```

You could change that file. There is also a similarly-named crc file that has a "createdTime" property - you *might* need to change that, too.

AFAIK there is no utility for editing delta commit histories. Seems like an interesting project.

Comment: Hey Peter, I tested your approach and apparently the content of the json files is not as important as the actual timestamp the delta log (*.json, *.json.crc) file is written to the file system. See opened issue: github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/1553

Comment: Okay, thank you for taking a look! That's unfortunate; I guess it's not really possible to falsify these at all.